# Can't locate CM.pm in @INC in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to run perl script which contain use CM, use CM_USER and use CM_METRICS statement and I am getting error "Can't locate CM.pm in @INC". I have also tried to install these using CPAN but it also giving me error "cannot install".

Comment: Why can't you install? what is error message when install fails?

Comment: You can also install modules by downloading tar.gz and then doing manual make install process.

Comment: I'm guessing that CM, CM_USER and CM_METRICS are some sort of packages local to your company, and not on CPAN.

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply. These are local packages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to install them from CPAN because they don't look like they are on CPAN.

Where did you get this program from? You'll need to ask the author where you can get the modules from.

Comment: You are right. These are local packages. Thanks for your help.